# Open Semantic UI React Modal by double clicking an event in react big calendar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, semantic-ui-react, react-big-calendar

I'm trying to open a Semantic UI React Modal when user double clicks an event in react big calendar. My doubleclick event handler is

```
eventDoubleClick() {    
    this.setState({
      open: true
    });    
    return <EditEvent />;
}
```

**EditEvent** is the class component which contains Modal. Its code is

```
class EditEvent extends React.Component {
 state = { open: false, startDate: moment() };
 show = dimmer => () => this.setState({ dimmer, open: true });
 close = () => this.setState({ open: false });
 open = () => this.setState({ open: true });

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);       
  }
  render() {
   <div>
     ... Semantic UI Modal goes here
   </div>
  }
 }
 export default EditEvent;
```

Haven't been able to find any help about this issue so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the Modal inside the component which had big calendar implementation and used state to set the open attribute for modal. It worked like a charm :)